# No instance for (Show b0) arising from a use of `print' The type variable `b0' is ambiguous

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to go through the Applicative example from Learn You a Haskell for Great Good! book.

my code is here:

```
class (Functor f) => Applicative f where  
    pure :: a -> f a  
    (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

instance Applicative Maybe where  
    pure = Just  
    Nothing <*> _ = Nothing  
    (Just f) <*> something = fmap f something  

main = do 
    print $ Just (+3) <*> Just 9 
    print $ pure (+3) <*> Just 10
    print $ pure (+3) <*> Just 9 
    print $ Just (++"hahah") <*> Nothing  
    print $ Nothing <*> Just "woot"
```

and I got this error message:

```
No instance for (Show b0) arising from a use of `print'
The type variable `b0' is ambiguous
Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Show Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
  instance Show Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
  instance (Integral a, Show a) => Show (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
    -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
  ...plus 23 others
In the expression: print
In a stmt of a 'do' block: print $ Nothing <*> Just "woot"
In the expression:
  do { print $ Just (+ 3) <*> Just 9;
       print $ pure (+ 3) <*> Just 10;
       print $ pure (+ 3) <*> Just 9;
       print $ Just (++ "hahah") <*> Nothing;
       .... }
```

Why does it fail and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in the last `print` line. Basically, you are applying a function `String -> b` by using `<*>`. It just so happens that you use `Nothing` to wrap the function, so there is no function in the end. The result of the application is some `Maybe b` where `b` is arbitrary, but only those `a`s that are instances of `Show` produce instances for `Maybe a`. But remember you have an arbitrary `b`, which need not be an instance of `Show`. The `print` however requires its argument to be an instance of `Show`. Since you cannot prove `b` to be instance of `Show` neither can you prove `Maybe b` to be an instance of `Show`, thus `print` does not apply to the value of type `Maybe b`.

To make it go away you must specify what exact type of function you meant to be contained. So that the result has some known type:

```
(Nothing :: Maybe (String -> Int)) <*> ...
```

or you could just provide the type for the whole expression that is passed as input of the `print`:

```
print (... :: Maybe Int)
```

Comment: `print ((stuff here) :: Maybe Int)` should also work.